# Qt Stylesheet affects whole widgets

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5.6, qstylesheet

I have a problem about Qt Stylesheets and I am using Qt 5.6 on windows.(This was not exist in Qt 5.5.1) I use this code piece, this is a QLabel inside a QDialog.

```
ui.newGroupNameLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel { color : black; }");
```

I also tried giving it a name usingQObject::setObjectName() and use an ID Selector to refer to it. But it still occurs.

It affects whole project. I mean that affecting other widgets. All the expand symbols change to plus sign. This QLabel is unrelated to this widget(below).
Did anyone face with this problem?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code entirely? And what component is newGroupNameLabel? Is it exactly QLabel? Not QGroupBox?

Comment: It is just a QLabel inside a layout of Widget,        horizontalLayout_14 = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout_14->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout_14"));
        newGroupNameLabel = new QLabel(verticalLayoutWidget);
        newGroupNameLabel->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("newGroupNameLabel"));

Comment: And what about verticalLayoutWidget? Do you set stylesheet for it?

Comment: You can try this syntax: `ui.newGroupNameLabel->setStyleSheet("color: black; <...> ")`.

Comment: No, UI is created from Designer

Comment: Please create a single-file test case for this issue. It shouldn't be longer than ~30 lines. And then file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in Qt 5.6.1 that will be released in few days.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52230